# Maximum instructions per CUDA kernel? Maximum operations per CUDA stream?

Tags: cuda, resources, gpgpu

Is there maximum number of CUDA operations which may be pending for a specific CUDA stream? I haven't seen such a limit in any documentation.

I am also interested in the related figure of the maximum number of instructions per CUDA kernel.

Comment: There is a maximum number of CUDA instructions per kernel: 2 million before CC 2.0, 512 million after.

Comment: OK, thank you. Where can I get more details about the maximum number limitation?

Comment: Please excuse the extensive edit, it's just that the answer merits a question actually requesting it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a maximum number of CUDA PTX instructions per kernel:

- **2 million** for GPUs with [Compute Capability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications) under 2.0 (i.e. before the Fermi microarchitecture)
- **512 million** for GPUs with Compute Capability 2.0 or higher (e.g. Fermi, Kepler, Maxwell, ...)

This information can be found in the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#features-technical-specifications.xml), just look for "Maximum number of instructions per kernel".

As for streams, if the kernels that run on a given stream respect this limit, there is no such stream instruction limit. As @talonmies pointed out, streams are a host side queue of operations, they have nothing to do with loading code onto the GPU.

Comment: I think that the only limit on the number of instructions is there, and then one could run many kernels sequentially on a given thread. So, there would be no limit for a stream as long as the kernel limit is respected.

Comment: No it really has nothing to do with streams at all. The instruction limit is how much code you can load from a module in one go and nothing else. Streams are a host side queue of operations, they have nothing to do with loading code onto the GPU, and those limits are completely unrelated to streams or stream capacity.

Comment: Indeed! I added this precision to the answer.